# Turn Monitor on from Google TV App

Tags: android, google-tv

Is there any way to turn a TV on or off [technically putting it to sleep] using a Google TV Android app using the standard Android APIs?

I understand that I could hack something together with IR or otherwise, but I'd really just like my app to perform the same function as pushing the TV Power button on my GTV remote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programatically toggling power for TV is not supported at this time. Please file a feature request here:
http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/

Comment: Thanks Megha.  Filed http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/issues/detail?id=38

Answer (score -2):

There are instructions on how to force the display on using a wakelock here:

[Wakelock is not turning on the screen? Help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689878/wakelock-is-not-turning-on-the-screen-help)

That said, this is for Android phones and tablets. Whether or not GoogleTV knows to send an "on" command to the TV (either over HDMI or IR), I'm not sure. You'll have to test it and let us know how it goes. :)

Comment: Method 1 and 3 here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6757206/1086560 were able to blank the screen, but not turn it off.