# How to light up screen or turn screen on?

Tags: android, mobile, bada

If screen is in off state, then how can I light up screen or turn screen on.

Answer for Android and Bada both are acceptable to me.

Thanks.

Comment: Either android or BADA, both are Different OS.

Comment: I am working on Bada and my friend working on Android and we both facing same problem.

Comment: @user1390378: Then the solution is you should ask about Bada and your friend should as about android. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to turn screen on and off programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561320/android-how-to-turn-screen-on-and-off-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On android you'll need to use a [PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) and get a [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html). You can have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689878/wakelock-is-not-turning-on-the-screen-help) for an example of how to use it.